# Unable to use marquee text with chronometer

Tags: android, scroll, textview, marquee, chronometer

I wanted to implement marquee for my textview to automatically scroll horizontal and at the same activity there will be a chronometer. When I implement two of them together, the scrolling textview is not working and the chronometers works. Once I comment the chronometer out the textview works. But I want it both to work at the same time. Is there any way to make that happen?

I tried using 
`textView.setSelected(true);` still not working

```
<com.ff.fbin.ScrollingTextView
    android:id="@+id/display_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Really Long Scrolling Text Goes Here.... ..... ............ .... ...."
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```